# Is it possible to catch errors that are not exceptions in Symfony?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, symfony-1.4

I have a try-catch block that iterates over a set of records like this:

```
try {
  foreach ( $json['location'] as $records ) {
    $location = DnaExtractionTable::getInstance()->find($records['id']);
    $location->setName($records['name']);
    $location->setLatitude($records['latitude']);
    $location->setLongitude($records['longitude']);
    $location->setCountryId($records['country_id']);
    $location->setRegionId($records['region_id']);
    $location->setIslandId($records['island_id']);
    $location->setRemarks($records['remarks']);
    $location->save();
  }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  ...
}
```

I can catch every exception that is thrown and continue without problems. But I am also trying to "catch" the errors, e.g. when a index does not exist in the `$records` array.

Is it possible to do that? How I can do it? I've been playing with `set_X_handler` functions without success.

**UPDATE 1:**

Following advices from comments and answers, I decided to implement a global error function:

```
function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
  if (error_reporting() == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (error_reporting() & $severity) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
  }
}
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');
```

But even if I try to force an error the code does not execute. Since I am developing with Symfony, is there a place to declare that function? Could be Symfony disabling or affecting the `set_error_handler` function?

**UPDATE 2:**

Symfony is definitely messing around with my error and exception handlers.

Turning on the debugging mode seemed to activate a Symfony custom exception handler that overrides error reporting.

Turning off the debugging mode seemed to bypass certain exceptions although my `try-catch` block is configured to catch general `Exception` objects. Really strange behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch this error: "Notice: Undefined offset: 0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373780/how-to-catch-this-error-notice-undefined-offset-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling errors as exceptions. Best methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455331/handling-errors-as-exceptions-best-methods)

Comment: I've updated the question, since I've already seen these solutions and did not solve my problem

Comment: Can you verify why it didn't work?

Is error_reporting turned off? Does the exceptions_error_handler every get called?

Comment: My fault. Symfony was being executed in production-mode. But now that I have turned it into debug-mode, Symfony seems to be implementing its own error handling mechanism that overrides my custom function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer to **[Handling errors as exceptions. Best methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455331/handling-errors-as-exceptions-best-methods)** for a way to throw exceptions when an error is raised.